# networkx: change node color in draw_circular

Tags: python, networkx

I draw a graph with networkx and draw_circular

```
  networkx.draw_circular(g)
```

I try change the color of some nodes, maybe with [draw_networkx_nodes](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes).
but for this, I need know the node position, how I can get the position of nodes in draw_circular ?
or directly, how I can change the color of some nodes in draw_circular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`draw_circular` will accept keyword arguments same as [`draw_networkx`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx). There is an optional argument `node_color` where you can supply colors for individual nodes. Argument passed to `node_color` must be a list with the length as number of nodes or a single value that will be used for all nodes. Color can be anything that is recognized by [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html).

So something like this would give the result below:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random
g = nx.random_graphs.erdos_renyi_graph(10,0.5)
colors = [(random(), random(), random()) for _i in range(10)]
nx.draw_circular(g, node_color=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**

Optinoally, you can get the positions of nodes for certain layout with the [`networkx.layout.circular_layout`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html?highlight=layout), etc..

Comment: why you use the `_i` var ? my question is about of `_`

Comment: @JuanPablo: No particular reason. Putting `_` at the beginning of unused indexes is a habit of mine. It serves no other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the previous answer (Avaris), using "[nodelist](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html)" attribute of "networkx.draw_networkx_nodes()" might be useful as well .

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

nodes = [0,1,2,3]
edges = [(0,1), (1,2), (3,1), (2,3)]
nodeListA = [0,1]
nodeListB = [2,3]    

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
position = nx.circular_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,position, nodelist=nodeListA, node_color="b")
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,position, nodelist=nodeListB, node_color="r")

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,position)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,position)

plt.show()
```

This generates the following figure:

[image]

You can also access the positions of the nodes from the variable "position". The output would look something like this:

```
In [119]: position
Out[119]: 
{0: array([ 1. ,  0.5], dtype=float32),
 1: array([ 0.49999997,  1.        ], dtype=float32),
 2: array([ 0.        ,  0.49999997], dtype=float32),
 3: array([ 0.5,  0. ], dtype=float32)}
```